# how to extract text from a selection of pages in a larger pdf using pymupdf?

Tags: python, pdf, nlp, pymupdf

I know there are many libraries to extract text from PDF. Specifically, I've been having some difficulty with pymupdf.
From the documentation here: [https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/app4.html#sequencetypes](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/app4.html#sequencetypes%20#)
I was hoping to use `select()` to pick an interval of pages, and then use `getText()` This is the doc I am using [linear_regression.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hDL97aVLCPP6BEjPovc4DN_A0r3z2ZPh/view?usp=sharing)

```
import fitz
s = [1, 2]
doc = fitz.open('linear_regression.pdf')
selection = doc.select(s)
text = selection.getText(s)
```

But I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-c05917f260e7> in <module>()
      6 # print(selection)
      7 # text = doc.get_page_text(3, "text")
----> 8 text = selection.getText(s)
      9 text

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'
```

So I'm assuming `select()` is not being used right
thanks so much

Comment: The problem is `doc.select(s)` is returning `None`. However, you do not define `doc` here so it's unclear why this is. Please edit your question to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks, @Kraigolas, I edited the post based on your feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select` here, according to [the documentation](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document.html#Document.select), modifies `doc` internally and does not return anything. In Python, if a function does not explicitly return anything, it will return `None`, which is why you see that error.

However, `Document` provides a [method](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document.html#Document.get_page_text) called `get_page_text` which allows you to get the text from a specific page (0 indexed). So for your example, you could write:

```
import fitz
s = [1, 2] # pages 2 and 3
doc = fitz.open('linear_regression.pdf')
text_by_page = [doc.get_page_text(i) for i in s]
```

Now, you have a list, where each item in the list is the text from a different desired page. A simple way to convert this to a string is:

```
text = ' '.join(text_by_page)
```

which joins the two pages with a space between the last word of the first page and the first word of the last (as if there was no page break at all).

Comment: This is super helpful @Kraigolas   I have a better sense of how to use pyMupdf

Comment: @KatieMelosto glad I could help!